# How to add a page/container below a video background in html css

Tags: html, css

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st0Co.png)I created a website with a video as my background for my front page. My problem is that when I enter new set of codes supposedly for another tab in the same page but below it, it does not work. i tried using div class container but it does not work. How to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Lakad Dalampasigan</title>
</head>
<body>

  <section class="showcase">
    <header>
      <h2 class="logo">LAKAD DALAMPASIGAN</h2>
      <div class="toggle"><img src="log1.png" width="90" height="90"></div>
    </header>
    <video src="ocean.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Lakad Dalampasigan </h2> 
      <h3></h3>
      <p>Climate has always changed and is always changing. 
        Climate change was reframed from an environmental concern to a public health issue prior to and during this ongoing crisis, and it may soon be deemed a public health emergency. </p>
      <a href="sec.html
" target="_blank">Learn more</a>
    </div>

    

   </section>


   



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide screenshot of current scenario.

Comment: Please provide much more detail

Comment: I provided a screenshot.  I just want to add a new container/page below that background video. But it does not work when i put the code.

Comment: For example this website has a video then when scrolling down there is an information page/tab in it https://theoceancleanup.com/

Comment: So what do you want content over the video?

Comment: I want to put a content/another information below the background video when i scroll down and the background will be different like a picture.

Comment: SO what you just neet to do is keep content that overlaped with video background in one container and leave rest to another container.